# Auto Incremental serial number for MySQL View

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, serial-number

Having a issue with my project need to insert an auto incremental value for my MySQL view, I would be nice if you guys help in solving this obstacle, Here is the code in which I wanna have auto incremental serial number (say S.No) as the first column.

```
    CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `srems_admin`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `emp_elec_consumption_view` AS
    SELECT 
        `t1`.`PFNUMBER` AS `PFNUMBER`,
        `emp`.`EMPNAME` AS `EMPNAME`,
        `t1`.`MonthAndYear` AS `MonthAndYear`,
        `qt`.`QTRSCODE` AS `QTRSCODE`,
        `t1`.`UNITS_CONSUMED` AS `UNITS_CONSUMED`,
        (`t2`.`FIXED_COMPONENT` + (`t1`.`UNITS_CONSUMED` * `t2`.`RATE_COMPONENT`)) AS `Amount`
    FROM
        (((`srems`.`mstqtroccu` `qt`
        JOIN `srems`.`mstemp` `emp`)
        JOIN `srems`.`msttariffrate` `t2`)
        JOIN (SELECT 
            `srems`.`tranmeterreading`.`PFNUMBER` AS `PFNUMBER`,
                (`srems`.`tranmeterreading`.`CLOSINGREADING` - `srems`.`tranmeterreading`.`OPENINGREADING`) AS `UNITS_CONSUMED`,
                CONCAT(CONVERT( IF((LENGTH(MONTH(`srems`.`tranmeterreading`.`READINGDATE`)) > 1), MONTH(`srems`.`tranmeterreading`.`READINGDATE`), CONCAT('0', MONTH(`srems`.`tranmeterreading`.`READINGDATE`))) USING UTF8), '/', RIGHT(YEAR(`srems`.`tranmeterreading`.`READINGDATE`), 2)) AS `MonthAndYear`,
                (SELECT 
                        `t`.`TRANSACTIONID`
                    FROM
                        `srems`.`msttariffrate` `t`
                    WHERE
                        (`t`.`TORANGE` > (`srems`.`tranmeterreading`.`CLOSINGREADING` - `srems`.`tranmeterreading`.`OPENINGREADING`))
                    LIMIT 1) AS `tariffplanid`
        FROM
            `srems`.`tranmeterreading`) `t1`)
    WHERE
        ((`t1`.`tariffplanid` = `t2`.`TRANSACTIONID`)
            AND (`t1`.`PFNUMBER` = `qt`.`PFNUMBER`)
            AND (`t1`.`PFNUMBER` = `emp`.`PFNUMBER`))
```

Pls insert the things at the correct place and post it as an comment to get S.No which should be auto-incremental starting from 1 and also it should be the first column, ty in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your view has no chance of working in MySQL anyway so you might as well give up.

MySQL does not allow subqueries in the `FROM` clause.  And your query is pretty complicated with lots of subqueries.

It also does not allow variables, so getting a row number is rather complicated.

Comment: Ups, why can't use variables in the view?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . I don't know.  Ask the people who wrote MySQL.